# How to solve : [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed while reading outlook email

Tags: python-2.7, outlook, imaplib

```
import email
import imaplib2
from collections import OrderedDict
import json

EMAIL_USER = 'client@apl.com'
EMAIL_PASSWORD = '*****'
EMAIL_SERVER = 'outlook.office365.com'

def read_mail_from_server():
    try:
        mail = imaplib2.IMAP4_SSL(EMAIL_SERVER, 993)
        mail.login(EMAIL_USER, EMAIL_PASSWORD)
        mail.select('INBOX')

        typ, raw_data = mail.search(None, 'ALL')      
        ids_list = len(raw_data[0].split())
        print(ids_list)
        ...
```

I have written a python code to read outlook emails using imaplib. I'm getting the below error when I run it, but with the same code and with different credentials I was to able to read emails from another server. What could be the reason for getting this error?

```
[Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Comment: Can you able to ping to server from the machine you are getting error?

Comment: @shaik moeed yes I can and getting back response from the server like "Reply from  40.100.29.242: bytes=32 time=46ms TTl=241

Comment: Try `telnet` to the port. If it's not possible, then the port is not open.

Comment: @shaikmoeed There I'm getting connection failed. My doubt is if the port is not open then how is it possible to connect to the same port (993) for different server

Comment: May the port is open for that server. You need contact admin team, they will open the port to the server you want to run.

Comment: @shaikmoeed you were right, the port was not open to office365. Now I'm able to access. Thank you